# JAX-RS (Apache CXF) Context injection via setter

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, kotlin

I'm trying to inject HttpServletRequest to my JAX-RS resource (Apache CXF implementation)  via @Context annotation in Kotlin. It works fine if I inject it via method parameter. But I don't want to "mess" my interfaces with that so I'd like to inject it via field/setter.

The thing with plain field injection is that the proxy has $ in its name which is an issue for kotlin as it is not able work with class names with dollar in name.

So I'm trying to do it via setter with this simple method:

```
var req : HttpServletRequest? = null

Context
fun setRequest(req : HttpServletRequest) {
    this.req = req
}
```

The thing is (and I believe it should be an issue in Java too), that the setter is called via reflection in org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils in method injectThroughMethod that throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

I tried to google this issue but with no luck. Did anyone had similar issue or is there something I'm doing wrong?

Btw I also created an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6190) in JIRA of CXF.

Comment: Kotlin can work with classes with "$" in their names, use backticks for escaping: `Foo$Proxy`

Comment: I'd suggest that you reproduce the same behavior in Java. It is likely that this issue is not connected to Kotlin at all.

Comment: I agree that this may not be Kotlin issue. That is why I didn't put it in name of question. I already disucussed it in the JIRA. I will try what they suggested and update this thread retrospectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to guys commenting CXF Jira issue, I managed to solve this.
To make setter injection working with CXF, you have to define setter also in your interface (not only on implementing class) and annotate it with @Context there (on interface). I'm unsure if this is really according to specification but it seems that CXF requires it that way.

Like this:

```
public MyInterface {
   @Context
   public void setRequest(HttpServletRequest req);
}

public MyClass implements MyInterface {
   private HttpServletRequest req;

   public void setRequest(HttpServletRequest req) {
      this.req = req;
   }
}
```

The explanation from Sergey from CXF Jira is:

> This is not a standard specific issue, it is all down to the fact that
>   the service object provided to the runtime is a proxy, and moving the
>   setter to the interface ensures that this setter is part of the proxy.
>   In my tests I do not have these setters on the main interface
>   representing the service but on the the dedicated interface like
>   Injectable.Alternatively, with Spring at least, enabling Cglib proxy
>   mode can help.